# Java's equivalent of C++'s double colon when writing a text about a code

Tags: java, methods, notation

What is the Java way to say in a text that a function belongs to a specific class?

For example, when writing a C++ commit message, I say

> `TimeInterval::toString()` now uses a UTC timezone

I.e., I utilize `::` to designate the `toString()` as a method of `TimeInterval`.

Is there a similar convention for Java?

Comment: The symbols used are not "a convention", they correspond to the syntax of the language.

Comment: You sometimes see a hash symbol to separate members, especially for instance methods: `TimeInterval#toString()`, or `#toString()` without the class. See the javadoc [`@see`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDDIEDI) tag.

Comment: The Oracle docs seem to use a dot (`.`): e.g., [`Date.toLocaleString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toString--).

Comment: Java 8 started to use a double colon (`::`) to reference methods, e.g., `reduce(Math::max)`.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. You use the same period that you use in code:

> The method `TimeInterval.toString()` returns a...

Comment: could also use method reference which would be TimeInterval::toString (no parens) but I think this would be rarer to see in documentation